# unique values from one column from each row

Tags: r

I am looking to find the unique values with the each row of a column.

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c('10','20','30','10','45','34'),
                          c('a','b','c','a','b'),
                          c("fs","pp","dd","dd")))

df$f7 <-paste0(df$V1,
               ',',
               df$V2,
               ',',
               df$V3,',',df$V4,',',df$V5,',',df$V6)   

df_1 <- as.data.frame(df[,c(7)])
names(df_1)[1] <-"f1"
```

The expected output is :
Row1 :10,20,30,45,34
Row2: a,b,c
Row3:fs,pp,dd

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
R

Answer (score 0):

We can loop over the rows with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1` - for rowwise loop), get the `unique` values and `paste`

```
apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```